# OR Tools formulate revenue

Tags: python, constraints, nonlinear-optimization, or-tools

I am seeking advice on formulating a problem to solve in OR tools.

The context is that I am a games owner, and in a shift, I can set varying number of games station. Let's say if I have 2 stations and 5 customers, then assume the most even distribution, which is 3 customers at a station and 2 customers at another station.

With different number of customers at a station, the game speed decreases. To maximise game speed, if I have 5 customers, the best solution is to have 5 stations such that each customer has 1 station each. But this increases the operational cost.

How do I represent the total game speed in this kind of scenario, where it involves even distribution of customers to station, and that the game speed depends on the number of customer at a station?

Answer (score 1):

OR-Tools does not contain a general non-linear solver.
You can access quadratic solvers, although not easily, using the MPSolver API (targeting SCIP or Gurobi).

If your problem can be discretized, you can use CP-SAT to solve your problem. See [this section on integer expressions](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/integer_arithmetic.md#step-function) .

Otherwise, OR-Tools is not what you are looking for.